# Coded UI Test - How to Pick multiple files from a location

Tags: automation, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I have some set of doc files(nearly 300+) which needs to be uploaded in a site. With Visual studio 2010 test automation, coded UI test, I have recorded the steps for a single file and when i run my code it worked.

Now, I want this to happen in loop, after uploading the 1st file, when the code runs again and when it hits the upload button it should pick the second file from my file location. How to code this ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: and what is the problem, where is ur code?

Comment: i have no idea how to code this, i made this with recording option (for single file).

Comment: after recording click generate code, go to UIMaps and click "Move code to UIMaps", this will generate the code in the UIMaps.cs file, and there you can adapt the code to loop through the files

Comment: i have generated the code, I'm in UIMaps but where is the option "Move code to UIMaps" ?? where will i see this

Comment: in the toolbar right above the ui actions pane

Answer (score 1):

Record and play back will work for one file that you recorded. You need to do some code changes by taking the recorded code and parameterize the files to the line of code.

1. First get the files from director 
   Use (Collection / Array) = Directory.GetFiles(@"FilePath"); //in C#
2. With this collection/array list you can pass arguments to your ui map code that you copied and repeat until all files get upload.